# How I load images in Plone 4.3 with Nginx

Tags: nginx, plone, plone-4.x

I follow this tutorial [Plone Deplayoing Nginx](https://docs.plone.org/4/en/manage/deploying/front-end/nginx.html) and created config file in NGINX:

```
add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
#add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; img-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'";
add_header Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only "default-src 'self'; img-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'";

# This specifies which IP and port Plone is running on.
# The default is 127.0.0.1:8080
upstream plone {
    server 127.0.0.1:8081;
}

# Redirect all www-less traffic to the www.site.com domain
# (you could also do the opposite www -> non-www domain)
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name asp.pro.br;
    rewrite ^/(.*) http://www.asp.pro.br/$1 permanent;
}

server {

    listen 80;
    server_name www.asp.pro.br;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/asp.pro.br.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/asp.pro.br.error.log;

    # Note that domain name spelling in VirtualHostBase URL matters
    # -> this is what Plone sees as the "real" HTTP request URL.
    # "Plone" in the URL is your site id (case sensitive)
    location / {
          proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081/VirtualHostBase/http/asp.pro.br:80/aspax/Portal/VirtualHostRoot/;
    }
}
```

But when open in browser the imagens don't load, how can I fix it?

[SOLUTION]

When DNS send `WWW` you must set up in `proxy_pass`:

```
          proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081/VirtualHostBase/http/asp.pro.br:80/aspax/Portal/VirtualHostRoot/;
```

Comment: Are the images are shown when you open Plone directly via the port 8081/aspax ? It might be that pillow is not installed correctly and images can't be converted as needed. If not, try without your Content-Security-Policy, to see if it works without that.

Comment: I used Squid before, and switched to Nginx cuz I up a application using Node... And this application works well in Nginx. And all imagens load up...

Comment: What does your browser console contain (error messages)?

Comment: Generally it's best to ask questions like this in the forum, community.plone.org

Comment: @T.KimNguyen  I tried a long time ago, but my user, i don't know... wasn't approved, and I like this community! But... thx for your attention, I'll try there again soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's first try to find out if, your Plone is working fine with images.
For that you should call it directly without any proxy like nginx in front.
If images are working, then we have to fix your nginx config.
Trying without your Content-Security-Policy part in nginx, to see if it works without that, would e my next step.
Every application works differently, therefor we should focus on what we need for Plone to run. And lucky you, that is not much.
If Plone was working in this setup with Squid, than it might be the nginx config.
Here are a working one:

```
server {
    listen 164.177.xx.xxx:80;
    server_name derico.de;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8090/VirtualHostBase/http/derico.de:80/Plone/VirtualHostRoot/;
    }
}
```

or with https:

```
server {
    listen 164.177.xx.xxx:443;
    server_name derico.de;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8090/VirtualHostBase/https/derico.de:443/Plone/VirtualHostRoot/;
    }
}
```

The site id here, is "Plone", for it is "aspax".

Make sure that your hostname in the proxy_pass directive is the same as for your server_name. That includes the www in your example.

An a bit more advanced and compact example can be found here: http://mrtango.planetcrazy.de/smart-compact-vhost-config-for-nginx-webserver-as-https-proxy-for-plone-cms.html

Comment: I saw that the unique change is the full ip, in your example to my (```proxy_pass```). I did it, but the images doen't apper. But when I access whithou a proxy ```http://www.asp.pro.br:8081/aspax/Portal``` all imagens are loaded. Look, I have a mountpoint ```aspax``` and a plone site ```Portal```.

Comment: Is will need setup on ```virtual_hosting``` in Zope?

Comment: did you try without your add_header lines?

Comment: and now, you don't have to configure anything in Zope for that. Also the ip doesn't matter that much. I use it like this because i have multiple ip's on that server. But just the port works too if you have a small setup.

Comment: also you should use the same hostname here: http/asp.pro.br:80 as you use for server_name, so it's with the www.

Comment: I got this with a debug toolbar... ```net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED``` for images and link in navbar ```net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT```, Will is probably is error in Rewrite Rule?

Comment: have a look and the urls for the request in your browser debug bar. They probably differ somehow more than they should. The config above like that and the one in the blog post works too for multiple websites. Without having a closer lok at your website, I can't tell you more.

Comment: I found the problem, the ```www``` in ```proxy_pass``` was missing, because the DNS is sending with ```www```.